# Is there a good way to initialize go mods with defaulting to dependency versions in the GOPATH?

Tags: go, go-modules

I'm starting the process of switching my applications to using go modules from currently not using any dependency manager. I want to use all of the same versions of the dependencies I currently use to avoid the risk of a different version of something causing unforeseen issues. Since I have a microservice architecture with a lot of applications I'm trying to figure out if there's a better way to do this than checking each application and its individual dependencies against what is currently in the build server's GOPATH.

Is there any way, even if just once when first initializing go mods, to have go modules default to the versions in the GOPATH.

If that's not possible (which I have a strong feeling it's not), is it possible to use go list or something similar to print the imported dependencies and the current git sha that exists in the GOPATH?

Comment: `go list` doesn't show commit info (you can see all the format options with `go help list`). You could likely use one of the legacy tools like `govendor` to build a `vendor` directory and init the module from that. Note that if any dependencies in GOPATH had switched to modules you may find you are using incorrect versions and will still probably see changes.

Answer (score 1):

From the root of your project directory:

```
go mod init
```

To pull in build (and optionally test dependencies):

```
go build ./... # ... notation will scan any subdirectories for any nested packages/tools
go test ./...  # optional
```

The above will pull the latest ([semver](https://semver.org/)) version of each dependency. This may *NOT* be the version you are using with a `GOPATH` build.

So to ensure you get the latest commit (which is what `GOPATH` builds use) - I'd go through each dependency in `go.mod` and issue a manual update to `master`. So for example lets say you had `logrus` as a dependency, to update to the latest commit:

```
go get github.com/sirupsen/logrus@master
```

If the latest `semver` matches the latest commit - no change will occur - but if not you will get a tag version plus commit style pseudo-version.

The Go wiki has other [go-modules daily workflows](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#daily-workflow) e.g. fast-forward, a month/year from now, to pull the latest  version of your dependencies into your `go.mod` (and `go.sum`):

```
go get -u ./...
```

but again be aware if a dependency does not use [semver](https://semver.org/) or has switched to a [v2 breaking change](https://blog.golang.org/v2-go-modules) - the above will not work.

The best practice is to eyeball the repo:

- does it support go-modules (i.e. does it have a `go.mod` at the top level or at the import path level)
- is the git repo tagged
- and if the latest commit is tagged

only then can you be sure you are getting the version you expect.

Comment: Yea I pretty much get how the importing works and what versions go mods default to. I was just hoping there was a less manual way to set my dependency versions to the ones I'm already using in all the repos I need to change. It looks like I may be out of luck on that though.

Comment: It really should be a manual process. GOPATH builds are the "wild west" - what may compile today may very well break tomorrow. It's a good idea to eyeball all your dependencies & their versions to ensure consistent builds.